# Find the 2 nearest points from a array

Tags: java, nearest-neighbor

I'm trying to get the 2 nearest points to another point from an array.

Here I only get the cosest. (i+=6 because I save POSITION and COLOR to the array) But how could I get the 2. closest?

```
nIdx = 0;
float dst1;
float dst2 = sqrt(vert[0] - x) + sqrt(vert[1] - y);
for (int i = 6; i < vert.length; i+=6) {
    dst1 = sqrt(vert[i] - x) + sqrt(vert[i+1] - y);
    if (dst2 > dst1) {
        nIdx = i;
        dst2 = dst1;
    }
}
```

I tryed to do this:

```
if (dst2 > dst1) {
    n2Idx = nIdx;
    nIdx = i;
    dst2 = dst1;
}
```

This does work in some cases. But if `nIdx` does swicht to fist index. `n2Idx` does not change to the last of `nIdx`.

Well I think I do somethink wrong:

```
float dst1 = sqrt(vert[0] - x) + sqrt(vert[1] - y);
float dst2 = sqrt(vert[6] - x) + sqrt(vert[7] - y);
for (int i = 0; i < vert.length; i+=6) {
    float dst = sqrt(vert[i] - x) + sqrt(vert[i+1] - y);
    //noinspection StatementWithEmptyBody
    if (dst >= dst2) {
    } else if (dst <= dst1) {
        dst2 = dst1;
        dst1 = dst;
    } else {
        dst2 = dst;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat `dst1` and `dst2` as an ordered pair, i.e. `dst1` is smaller and `dst2` is larger (or both distances are equal). When you walk your list of points, compute candidate distance `dst`, and do one of the following:

- If `dst` is greater than or equal to `dst2`, do nothing
- if `dst` is less than or equal to `dst1`, move `dst1` to `dst2`, and assign `dst` to `dst1`
- Otherwise, assign `dst` to `dst2`.

Upon completion of the loop `dst1` and `dst2` will have the two smallest distances:

```
index ind1 = 0;
index ind2 = 6;
float dst1 = sqrt(vert[ind1] - x) + sqrt(vert[ind1+1] - y);
float dst2 = sqrt(vert[ind2] - x) + sqrt(vert[ind2+1] - y);
// Make sure dst1 and dst2 are ordered to begin with
if (dst2 < dst1) {
    float td = dst1;
    dst1 = dst2;
    dst2 = td;
    ind1 = 6;
    ind2 = 0;
}
// Start loop at 12, because we have processed the first two indexes
for (int i = 12 ; i < vert.length; i += 6) {
    float dst = sqrt(vert[i] - x) + sqrt(vert[i+1] - y);
    if (dst >= dst2) {
        continue;
    }
    if (dst <= dst1) {
        dst2 = dst1;
        ind2 = ind1;
        dst1 = dst;
        ind1 = i;
    } else {
        dst2 = dst;
        ind2 = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with move and how could i the get the index of the array.

Comment: @DarioKowalski "move" is the same as "assign". To get indexes, store `ind1` and `ind2` along with `dst1` and `dst2`. Every time you do something to `dstX`, do the same thing to `indX`.

Comment: It does wwork in some cases but sometimes both get to index 0.